# Closed Loop Gain with Phase Reversal in 741 Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, loop-gain, 741-opamp

This is a typical example of negative feedback in an Op-Amp -
[image]

For this case, the feedback of the output can be controlled using a resistor divider, and let's call the feedback fraction to be **X**. We can thus find the closed gain to be -

$$G_{CL} = \frac{G_{OL}}{1 + XG_{OL}}$$ using the open loop gain for the op-amp. As the open loop gain is very high, the equation reduces to **1/X**. So, we can get a sizeable gain in this case using a proper resistor divider, but this retains the phase of the input waveform in V_in.

Now here is where I'm facing a problem. If I need to reverse the phase by 180 degrees for the output, maintaining the same magnitude of gain, how should I change the connections in the existing circuit without adding any other component? Using the equation -

$$V_{out} = G_{OL}(V_{non-inv}-V_{inv})$$, I see that I need to ground the non-inverting input and V_inverting should have a voltage of **(XV_out + V_in)**, so that the gain remains same with a change in sign. But I have not been able to implement this, and this configuration distorts my input, though my output voltage is the same as it was with the phase retention gain -

[image]

Can someone help me out in this? It would be of great help.

**NOTE:** It is possible to shift the phase by 180 degrees using a three pole RC filter. I wish to know if there is an alternative to this without adding any new component.

Edit: Here is the actual V_in, and this doesn't get distorted for the Phase retention gain -
[image]

Here is the output that I get in both cases, the phase reversed or phase retained gains -

[image]

Here is the distorted V_in for the phase reversed gain in my case -
[image]

Comment: You need to search for "noninverting amplifier". There is documentation everywhere on this.

Comment: I have been searching everywhere and reading up articles. I came to know that I can actually use a cascaded RC filter to shift the phase by 180 degrees, but isn't it possible without using the filter?

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? Show us a sketch of your input sinusoid and your desired output sinusoid.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've added the simulations.

Comment: Why are people still using 741? I used them in 1971, 50 years ago. There are so many better op-amps out there today.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I'm just a beginner in Analog electronics, and I've been advised to start with the basic design of a 741 Op-Amp, and then move on to advanced ones.

Comment: @DavideAndrea   LM741 is the "start" of the op-amp generations (in fact uA709 which was not very stable and one must add externally capacitor compensation). All the "problems" of this amplifier may be best known because it is a poor op-amp. It was the first which learned me what was the difference between "low-signal bandwidth" and "large-signal bandwidth" because of the "slew-rate" ...

Comment: @Antonio51: Oh, I know: I am old enough to remember when the 741 came out.

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Ok. We are then two :-) As teacher, I would only explain that, for the beginner in analog electronics, if one know the "bad" device and its defects ... one will more appreciate the "newest" version ...  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first remember the inverting amplifier:

[image: op-amp inverting amplifier]

(Image source: [Electronics Post - Application of Op-Amp as Inverting Amplifier](https://electronicspost.com/application-of-op-amp-as-inverting-amplifier-non-inverting-amplifier-and-voltage-follower/))

What you are trying to do is to build this inverting amplifier with zero-Ohm resistors: Rf=Ri=0R.

Think about what to expect at the output considering the gain formula, Av=-Rf/Ri.

What you need to do is to use equal and non-zero resistances for both resistors, taking the bias currents and source's drive capability into account.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! I would have to look into the inverting amplifier some more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without additional resistors because you short-circuit input with output.

[Inverting buffer with op-amps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/inverting-buffer-with-op-amps)

If you need to switch between inverting and non inverting try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDQpHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would actually connect a resistor divider in between, I didn't show this in the picture. But then, how do the resistors play a role in inverting the output?

Comment: They act as a voltage divider and separate in and out. Op Amp wants to equalise voltage between +in and -in.

Comment: Only add a switch between the + input and ground ... And you have the two schematic. :-) And if it is an electronic switch, you have a digital "modulator".